# mapping of an image on another image :how to do in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

i have an image ,imageA (cropped from any image)
how to map it on imageB at top left... so that (x,y) coordinates of one image maps on (x,y) coordinates of other image.

Comment: Do you want to scale `A` to the size of `B`?  Otherwise, the x,y coordinates are simply the subscript indices of the image matrices.  Top-left is the easiest case, but you just have to add a constant to "shift" `A` around "on" `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you just want to overwrite the top left corner of B with A

```
[m, n, ~] = size(imageA);
imageB(1:m, 1:n, :) = imageA;
```

Remember to take care with the number of colour channels.